# как сравнивать два слова

Tags: c, строки, сравнение, локализация

как сделать цикл сравнения 2 слов по буквенно с даного масива?
если а>b return 1 b>a return -1.в чем проблема моего?

```
    int mystrcmp(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    char abetka[100] = {'А', 'а', 'Б', 'б', 'В', 'в', 'Г', 'г', 'Ґ', 'ґ', 'Д', 'д', 'Е', 'е', 'Є', 'є', 'Ж', 'ж', 'З', 'з',
                        'И', 'и', 'І', 'і', 'Ї', 'ї', 'Й', 'й', 'К', 'к', 'Л', 'л', 'М', 'м', 'Н', 'н', 'О', 'о', 'П', 'п', 'Р',
                        'р', 'С', 'с', 'Т', 'т', 'У', 'у', 'Ф', 'ф', 'Х', 'х', 'Ц', 'ц', 'Ч', 'ч', 'Ш', 'ш', 'Щ', 'щ', 'ь', 'Ю', 
                        'ю', 'Я', 'я' };
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (abetka[i] == a[i]) {
            if (a[i] > b[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то код не сильно соответствует заданию. Массив какой-то зачем-то...

Comment: нужно сделать иммено при помощи масива.strcmp либо простые функции сравнения строк не подходят

Comment: А  что делать, если, например, в первой строке - буква из массива, а во второй - английская? или цифра? или наоборот? Делаете-то вы ерунду, но чтоб ее исправить - нужно точное ТЗ, без которого, сами знаете...

Comment: такого быть не должно,просто сравнение двух украинских слов

Comment: Я не понимаю, нафига для озвученного (маловменяемого, кстати) задания надо сравнивать переданную `a` с этим массивом, да к тому же посимвольно. Ну и смысла массива не понимаю - от слова "совсем". Думаю, Вам для начала надо сосредоточиться не на решении, а на формулировании задания.

Comment: задание сравнить два слова,без strcmp и без простых циклов сравнения строк.Именно при помощи даного масива

Comment: Для сравнения двух слов массив НЕ НУЖЕН!!! и в решении задачи он не поможет НИКАК. Более того, вообще неясно, как его можно "пристегнуть" к решению задачи.

Comment: что же нужно?ваш вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так (не компилировал, но идея должна быть понятна):

```
int mystrcmp(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    char * abetka = "АаБбВвГг......";
    for(;*a && *b; ++a, ++b)
    {
        char * apos = strchr(abetka,*a);
        char * bpos = strchr(abetka,*b);
        if (apos == NULL || bpos == NULL)
        {
            puts("Я гадав, що це неможливо...");
            abort();
        }
        if (apos < bpos) return  1;   // a раньше по алфавиту
        if (apos > bpos) return -1;   // b раньше по алфавиту
    }
    if (*a && !*b) return -1;    // b короче
    if (!*a && *b) return  1;    // a короче
    return 0;
}
```

Когда должно возвращать 1, когда -1 - смотрите сами. У меня 1, если `a<b`, грубо говоря...